# PollerMetadata with KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter

Tags: spring-integration

Is it possible to use `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` (`KafkaMessageListenerContainer`) with Poller to read from Kafka every x minutes?

I try creating bean

```
 @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata defaultPoller() {

        PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
        pollerMetadata.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
        return pollerMetadata;
    }
```

But looks like it is not effecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; the `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` is push, not pull, technology.

Use the inbound channel adapter instead.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/kafka.html#kafka-inbound-pollable

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow(ConsumerFactory<String, String> cf)  {
    return IntegrationFlow.from(Kafka.inboundChannelAdapter(cf, "myTopic")
                .groupId("myDslGroupId"), e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000)))
            .handle(System.out::println)
            .get();
}
```

or

```java
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "fromKafka", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))
@Bean
public KafkaMessageSource<String, String> source(ConsumerFactory<String, String> cf)  {
    KafkaMessageSource<String, String> source = new KafkaMessageSource<>(cf, "myTopic");
    source.setGroupId("myGroupId");
    source.setClientId("myClientId");
    return source;
}
```

You must ensure that the `max.poll.interval.ms` is larger than your poll interval, to avoid a rebalance.

Comment: interesting, any other benefit choosing KafkaMessageSource over KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "benefit"; they are for different use cases.

Comment: use case is to constantly pull data from kafka, process the data and transfer to database.

Comment: Well, one is push, the other is pull - i.e. fetch records when needed rather than as soon as they are available. There is no need for a poller with the message-driven approach.

Comment: If I stick with  KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter, and the processing of message takes a lot of time, will that trigger rebalancing?  should i configure 
max.poll.interval.ms accordingly?

Comment: You need to adjust `max.poll.records` and/or `max.poll.interval.ms` with a generous margin to avoid any possibility of a forced rebalance.

Comment: So If there will be MessageHandler as an output channel for the output of the adapter, with a while(true) (long un controlled processing) there will unpredicted consequences for the whole flow.

Comment: Yes; you must poll the consumer within the configured interval, otherwise the broker will consider the consumer to be dead and drop the consumer from the group; this will be detected on the next poll. If there is only one instance of the app, the partitions will be re-assigned. If there are multiple instances, the partitions will immediately be assigned to other instances. If you can't avoid that, then perhaps Kafka is not the appropriate technology for your application.